# Why does PowerShell think C:\Windows\System32\WDI doesn't exist? How can I copy these log files with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I know that `C:\Windows\System32\WDI` exists and has contents. We need to copy these contents from hundreds of machines for security analysis. We tried:

```
Copy-Item 'C:\Windows\System32\WDI' -Destination .\my_output_dir\wdi -recurse
```

This works on my personal computer (I think I have myself permissions for system32 though the gui), but not for my colleague on other machines.

On other machines, we get an error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\WDI' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item 'C:\Windows\System32\WDI' -Destination .\my_output_dir\wdi  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\System32\WDI:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

It's not feasible to go into the GUI on every machine to give myself the necessary permissions. How can this be achieved purely through powershell? We have administrative credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likeliest explanation is that the inability to find the directory is due to running in *32-bit* PowerShell sessions on 64-bit systems: the `System32` directory that 32-bit processes see doesn't have a `WDI` subdirectory.

You have two options:

- Make sure that you use 64-bit PowerShell sessions everywhere.
- Construct the directory path *conditionally*, so that in 32-bit sessions it accesses the directory via the `SysNative` folder, which refers to the true, (paradoxically named) 64-bit `System32` folder; using `Get-ChildItem` as an example:

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemRoot\$(('SysNative', 'System32')[[Environment]::Is64BitProcess])\WDI"
```

Note:

- If you still need support for the long-obsolete v2 of PowerShell, substitute `$env:ProgramFiles -notlike '*(x86)'` for `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`.
- Accessing the files and directories in the `WDI` directory requires *elevation* (running as admin).